# Angularjs Material md-tabs issue with firefox

Tags: angular-material

I am using md-tabs in md-dialog. It works fine in Chrome but creates issue in firefox. My code is,

```
<md-dialog aria-label="Mango (Fruit)">
<form>
<md-toolbar>
  <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
    <h2>Join Us</h2>
    <span flex></span>
  </div>
</md-toolbar>
<md-dialog-content style="max-width:800px;max-height:810px; " ng-cloak>
  <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom  md-align-tabs="bottom">
    <md-tab label="Register">
      <md-content class="md-padding">
        <md-input-container class="md-icon-float md-block">
            <!-- Use floating label instead of placeholder -->
            <label>Name</label>
            <input ng-model="name" type="text">
          </md-input-container>

          <md-input-container md-no-float class="md-block">
            <label>Phone Number</label>
            <input ng-model="phone" type="text" ng-required="true">
          </md-input-container>

          <md-input-container>
            <label>Country Code</label>
            <md-select ng-model="countrycode">
              <md-option><em>None</em></md-option>
              <md-option ng-repeat="c_code in countrycodes track by $index" ng-value="c_code.code">
                {{c_code.name}}
              </md-option>
            </md-select>
          </md-input-container>

          <md-input-container class="md-block">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input ng-model="password" type="password" ng-required="true">
          </md-input-container>
      </md-content>
      <md-dialog-actions layout="row">
        <md-button  class="md-primary" ng-click="register(name,phone,countrycode,password)" style="margin-right:20px;" >
          Register
        </md-button>
      </md-dialog-actions>
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Login">
      <md-content class="md-padding">
          <p class="text-center">{{error}}</p>
          <md-input-container md-no-float class="md-block">
            <label>Phone Number/Email</label>
            <input ng-model="phone" type="text" ng-required="true">
          </md-input-container>

          <md-input-container class="md-block">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input ng-model="password" type="password" ng-required="true">
          </md-input-container>
      </md-content>
      <md-dialog-actions layout="row">
        <md-button  class="md-primary" ng-click="login(phone,password)" style="margin-right:20px;" >
          Login
        </md-button>
      </md-dialog-actions>
    </md-tab>

  </md-tabs>
</md-dialog-content>
```

In firefox it is not visible i.e. md-tabs moves to left of dialog box, keeping white space on right. please let me know, how to fix this.